# Rotate images for different durations inside thread

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to implement an Android app that needs to rotate the images for different duration.Below is my code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run()
          {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run()
              {
                while(true)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < lstData.size(); i++)
                    {
                        String pathFile = JG.PathFiles + lstData.get(i);
                        File f = new File(pathFile);
                        if(f.exists())
                        {
                            String fileName = lstData.get(i);
                            String [] extens = fileName.split("\\.");
                            if(extens.length > 1)
                            {
                                Log.d("test ... .. . ", "" + pathFile);

                                vImage.setImageBitmap(GetImage(pathFile));

                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(duration);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }  
              }
            });
          }
    }).start();

public static Bitmap GetImage(String pathImage)
    {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathImage, options);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

and I have following two issues:

**1.** The image are not shown .

**2.** The mobile screen is locked while thread is running (I want allow use the do something like open `SharedPreferene` while images are rotating). Anyone have alternative solutions?

Comment: Why not using ViewFlipper ?

Comment: Can I use it to rotate the images for different durations??

Comment: how actually you rotate ?with a different images ?

Comment: The duration is applied over all the ViewFLipper, however for each image duration you can change the interval onAnimation end event for the next image in queue.

Comment: Just change the image path for different durations

Comment: Thank you Jibran Khan for your reply and I will test it.

Comment: Whats your issue ? Its different duration for different images or the two you mentioned in the question ?

Comment: If I use your solution I think it would solve the issues, I will test it, Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RotateThread implements Runnable {
   private View view;
   private double duration;

   private static final float ROTATE_FROM = 0.0f;
   private static final float ROTATE_TO = -10.0f * 90.0f;

   public RotateThread(final View view, final double duration) {
      this.view = view;
      this.duration = duration;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      RotateAnimation r; // = new RotateAnimation(ROTATE_FROM, ROTATE_TO);
      r = new RotateAnimation(ROTATE_FROM, ROTATE_TO,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
      r.setDuration((long) duration);
      r.setRepeatCount(0);
      try {
          Thread.sleep(500);
          this.view.startAnimation(r);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }}
```